# Undefined reference to function, but it's all defined

Tags: c, function, codeblocks, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I have problems with running multiple files after creating a library, which in this case I called `"calcola.h"`.

It seems all right to me, but the error `"undefined error somma, error: ld returned 1 exit status"` keeps appearing. "somma" is the name of the file where I created the function which does the sum between two numbers.

At this point, I tried to run my files manually through the terminal: firstly, I created the main.exe file by typing `gcc -o main main.c somma.c`, then I ran the main.exe file by simply typing `main.exe`, and it worked perfectly, so I know that my code is correct for sure.

I already checked if the compiler was installed correctly through the terminal, and I already added it to the environment variable in PATH.
Is there something that could fix this problem? It's been several days that I've been dealing with this, but nothing. Can someone help me?

At the end of the day this code does the sum between two numbers entered by the user.

Hear's **main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "calcola.h"
    
int main() {
    float num1, num2, x;
    scanf("%f%f", &num1, &num2);
    x = somma(num1, num2);
    
    printf("%f\n", x);
    getchar();
}
```

Here is the header, **calcola.h**:

```
float somma(float, float);
```

And here is the function, **somma.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "calcola.h"

float somma(float a, float b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Better to post relevant code _here_ as _text_ and not as a link to a picture some place else.

Comment: Do you mean to write the code directly as a text?

Comment: Yes. A copy and paste works well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I appreciate that! I'm just new here, so thanks.

Comment: A header file is not a library.  Some headers are *adjuncts* to libraries, but `#include`ing a header is orthogonal to creating and / or linking to a library, and to building a library from multiple sources.

Comment: Re “"undefined error somma, error: Id returned 1 exit status"”: Did you retype this? Or run it through some OCR? Or let spelling correction change it? An error message in linking with Unix or Unix-like tools typically comes from the linker, which is named `ld` (letters in Lima Delta) not `Id` (India Delta). Do not retype error messages. Copy and paste it exactly, including line breaks. Do not let spelling correction change it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Many Windows compilers (like `cygwin` for one) will automatically append the `.exe` if you specify an output binary with no extension. Yeah, I know...

Comment: OP, you need to post your library compilation command. How are you creating this library? Is it meant to be dynamically linked? We have almost no information to go on here besides the command that worked...

Comment: Have you added `somma.c` to the codeblocks project?

Comment: I would suggest - instead of fighting the compiler install eclipse CDT and you will not have to think how to properly invoke gcc.

Comment: @EricPostpischil actually it's ld (letters in Lima Delta), sorry for writing wrong

Comment: OT: You're not checking the return value from `scanf()` and both `num1` & `num2` are uninitialised... Risking a "kaboom" from the math library... Always validate user input...

Comment: @AndreaSestito So, did you add `somma.c` to the codeblocks project?

Comment: @TedLyngmo all these files are not in a project. They are single file in the same folder

Comment: The folder doesn't matter. `somma.c` needs to be added to the codeblocks _project_ along with `main.c`. If you look at the list of Sources in your codeblocks project, is `somma.c` and `main.c` there? If not, add them.

Comment: @TedLyngmo how can I check if it's added?

Comment: Look in the list of _Sources_. It'll probably look something like [this](https://wiki.codeblocks.org/images/c/c1/RemoveFile.png). Click Project->Add files... to add files to the project.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I didn't create a project, but 3 single files. So my workspace is empty .

Comment: Then that's the problem. If you have multiple source files, you must tell the IDE what files that should be compiled and linked together. Create a project, add `main.c` and `somma.c` to the project. Problem solved.

Comment: See https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Creating_a_new_project

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed your issue.  The ensuing comments pretty much summarize what I would also suggest which is to choose and utilize an IDE that works with the platform on which you are coding.  To maybe make what these comments are saying a bit clearer, following are a couple of images showing building a project with the header file and two source code files you note above using "Code::Blocks".

That development platform like others (e.g. "Visual Studio", etc.) usually provide a method to add and associate various header and source files together in a project, along with allowing the association of any custom libraries, such that the developer application will then perform the needed compilation and linking to produce the end application code.

Using your code as an example, following is a sample selection to add a supplemental header file and/or supplemental source code file to the project.

[image: Addition of a file to a project]

Resulting in a directory structure of files for the project.

[image: Structure of files]

Once all of the needed files for the project are associated, the desired program file can be built by compilation and linkage.

Testing out your code resulted in the following output in a terminal window.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Cola/bin/Release$ ./Cola 
2.333 4.555
6.888000
```

To be sure, this is not an advocacy for one IDE over another, but just a visual example of how an IDE would be helpful in making your coding easier.